# Request Filter in jersey changing httpheader

Tags: java, web-services

I want to change  the Authorization header in request filter.My auth header is coming in below format

```
Authorization:x,y
```

I want to change it to below

```
Authorization:a,b,c
```

I implemented jersey Container filter

```
public class MyRequesrFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
{

@Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

List<String> authHeaders= request.getRequestHeader("Authorization") ;  

authHeaders=//My new auth header;


}
```

But how to set my new auth header.I cannot find any setHttpHeader method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as below to set header in request

```
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

      MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = request.getRequestHeaders();

      headers.add("auth_user", "user1");
      request.setHeaders((InBoundHeaders)headers);

      return request;
}
```